# Non-equilibrium tides and tidal flow fields

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tidal-effect

For
i) an ideal rotation ellipsoid entirely covered with a thin shell of water
ii) locked mutual rotation
iii) non-rotating earth
iv) further conditions (?)
the idea of equilibrium tides with a stationary state do apply. In an inertial, non-rotating frame (with origin e.g. at the c.o.earth or c.o.mass) there is collective motion of the water which flows with a fixed shape around the earth, following the rotating earth-moon axis.

I am interested in relaxing these conditions (i - iii) slightly such that an additional flow field is superimposed.

Are there any simulations showing the large scale flow field?